# merge a branch into a new sub directory on the master

Tags: git

I have a repo with master and feature branch. I would like to know if there is a way 
to merge the feature branch as a new sub directory under the master branch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`git am` has a `--directory=<dir>` switch, so you tell which directory to use as the base of the applying patches.

So, first make a `git format-patch` and then apply them:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git format-patch -o ../patches/ master..feature-branch
$ git am --directory=feature-subdir ../patches/*
```

`--directory=<dir>` is passed to `git apply` by `git am`. From `git help apply`:

```
   --directory=<root>
       Prepend <root> to all filenames. If a "-p" argument was also passed, it is applied before prepending the new root.

       For example, a patch that talks about updating a/git-gui.sh to b/git-gui.sh can be applied to the file in the working tree modules/git-gui/git-gui.sh by running git apply
       --directory=modules/git-gui.
```

Comment: git format-patch -o ../patches/ master..feature-branch ../patches/0001-comment --upto ../patches/0014-comment It then gives me an error stating that certain files do not exist in the index Patch failed at 0001 "comment" When you have resolved this problem run "git am --resolved". If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git am --skip". To restore the original branch and stop patching run "git am --abort". I tried running git am --abort. It still does not work. Am I missing naything?

Comment: @user1801669 Hmm... What I said would work if your commits only have changes of files that don't exist in `master`. If that's not the case, I don't think what you want is achievable at all - you should break your commits to have commits for existing files only and commits for non-existing files, and then do what I said. Or manually edit your patches. There's no way for git to know what changes are applied to a different file and which not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Simply move the content of the feature branch to a directory, then merge it with *master*.

Comment: That won't work if the two branches share history, in that case the files would only end up in the subdirectory.